# How to get LocalStorage data from a dataset I have got after running a specific analysis to get all flows in many websites

Tags: javascript

after running analysis on many websites. I got two datasets that contain all the flows from the websites crawled. I need a script that take only LocalStorage from each dataset and put it in a new file to carry on with my analysis. Those datasets files contain information that irrelevent for me such as SessionStorage, timestamps etc.. .I have tried to make script in JavaScript to do that but just didn't work. Does anyone have an idea how it should be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share where you stack?

Comment: @amd, I don't know how to make a script for that basically. I am sure the one I made have no meaning